# Apply a function to all the elements of a data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, apply

I am trying to apply some transformations to all the elements in a dataframe.

When using the regular apply functions, I get a matrix back and not a dataframe. Is there a way to get a dataframe directly without adding `as.data.frame` to each line?

```
df = data.frame(a = LETTERS[1:5], b = LETTERS[6:10])

apply(df, 1, tolower) #Matrix
apply(df, 2, tolower) #Matrix
sapply(df, tolower)   #Matrix

as.data.frame(sapply(df, tolower)) # Can I avoid "as.data.frame"?
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

We can use `lapply` and assign it back to 'df'

```
df[] <- lapply(df, tolower)
```

The `[]` preserves the same structure as the original dataset.  Using `apply` convert it to a `matrix` and that is not recommended.

Answer (score 8):

Here's a way using `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
df  %>% mutate_each(funs(tolower))
```